# how do I flip image left to right( mirror)

Tags: images, flip

how do I flip image left to right(mirror) on a secondary display with windows XP professional?
Want to Show my desktop using a teleprompter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "Display Settings" of the Primary and Secondary monitors.

Go to Display Properties > Settings tab > Now choose the Primary and Secondary monitors to show the images. Also, you can flip your monitors around, change the display resolution, orientation and other settings.

Or,

Try "Ultramon" to flip the monitors. It provides number useful features when multiple monitors connected.

Hope this helps.